# Mplabx 5.15 on Ubuntu 18.04 can not use ICD 3

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, mplab

I keep getting this error with ICD 3 when attempting self test:
Could not connect to the selected hardware tool. Please make sure the tool is not being used by another project in MPLAB X.

The device works fine under Ubuntu 12.04.  Mplab can see the ICD3 device because it gets the correct serial number.  lsusb reports the same values that Mplab reports as well.  I tried running Mplab as root and that made no difference - this is not a permissions problem.

I tried this solution: https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1051283.aspx but it did not work.  I also tried to close all projects so I had  in the projects bar, and got the same error.

I tried the udevadm as suggested by this comment: https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1083236.aspx an it shows Mplab is trying to talk to the ICD 3:

```
$ udevadm monitor --property
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[3219.382129] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.2/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=bind
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.2/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
DRIVER=usbfs
INTERFACE=255/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v04D8p9009d0100dcFFdsc00dp00icFFisc00ip00in00
PRODUCT=4d8/9009/100
SEQNUM=3378
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=255/0/0

UDEV  [3219.387110] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.2/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=bind
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.2/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
DRIVER=usbfs
ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Vendor Specific Class
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Microchip Technology, Inc.
INTERFACE=255/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v04D8p9009d0100dcFFdsc00dp00icFFisc00ip00in00
PRODUCT=4d8/9009/100
SEQNUM=3378
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=255/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=3219386787
```

A few seconds later it unbinds.  So far I'm just hearing crickets on the Microchip forum.  Anyone else tried using ICD 3 under Ubuntu 18?
Mike

Answer (score 0):

After much head beating, I found that there were a lot of .jar files in the microchip mplab directory.  But Java was not installed on my version of Ubuntu.  After installing openjdk (and placing the correct device for loop back) I got MPLAB to talk to the ICD 3.

I am really surprised this was not obvious.  If you have any MPLAB problems under Ubuntu 18.04, check if java is installed! (sudo apt install default-jre)